# Reactjs react router dom useParams not working with dynamic url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0" and "react": "16.8.6",

I have this:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
   <Route path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

and in the Users component:

```
const param = useParams();
console.log(param);
```

So if I enter `/users` or `/users/10` always param renders as empty object. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component will only render its **first** match.

The first `Route` that matches the path `/users/10` is `<Route path="/users" component={Users} />`.

This means that even though you have a second `Route` that says the "10" should be a param called `id`, its ignoring it and treating it as the first `Route` does which has no params.

You can easily correct this behavior by using the [`exact`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop on the first `Route`:

```js
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

This will instruct `react-router` to only match that route if the URL matches the `path` **exactly**, and will allow `/users/10` to pass down to the `Route` you actually want it to match. Then you will have the params available that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using Switch. In my case, by mistake I imported useParams from 'react-router' and not from 'react-router-dom'. After import

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I got good params.

Answer (score 0):

import your useparams from react-router-dom instead of react-router
Like this :

```js
import {useParams }  from "react-router-dom";

const {yourId} = useParams();
console.log(yourId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```